# what is the problem with my code. it keeps on displaying this error message

Tags: python, graph, kivy, real-time

i am trying to make  a software that records microphone data in realtime but it keeps on coming up with an error. " TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument '__no_builder'"
i have looked through the code but cant seem to find any problems.
i am using atom to code.
there is a .kv and .py file

```
python file
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.garden.graph import MeshLinePlot
from kivy.clock import Clock
from threading import Thread
import audioop
import pyaudio
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder

Window.borderless = True

def capture_mic_data():
    chunk = 1024
    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    CHANNELS = 1
    RATE : 44100
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    s =  p.open(format = FORMAT, channels = CHANNELS, rate = RATE, input = True,frames_per_buffer =chunk)

    global levels
    while True:
        data =  s.read(chunk)
        mx = audio.rms(data,2)
        if len(levels) >= 100:
            levels = []
        levels.append(mx)



class Logic(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self,):
        super(Logic,self).__init__()
        self.plot = MeshLinePlot(color=[1,0,0,1])

    def start(self):
        self.ids.graph.add_plot(self.plot)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.get_value,0.0001)

    def stop(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.get_value)

    def get_value(self,dt):
        self.plot.points =[(i,j/5) for i,j in enumerate(levels)]


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("main.kv")

levels =[]
capture_mic_data_thread = Thread(target =  capture_mic_data)
capture_mic_data_thread.daemon = True
capture_mic_data_thread.start()
MainApp().run()
```

kivy file

```
Logic:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: [1,.8]
            Graph:
                id: graph
                xlabel: "Amplitude"
                ylabel: "Sample"
                x_grid_label : True
                y_grid_label : True
                background_color : 0.429,0.3,0.423,1
                x_ticks_minor : 10
                x_ticks_major :5
                color : 1,1,0,1
                ymax: 500
                ymin: 0
                xmax: 100
                border_color : 1,1,0,1

            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: [1,.1]
                orientation : "horizontal"
                Button:
                    size_hint:[0.2,1]
                    text: "START"
                    bold : True
                    on_press: root.start()

                Button:
                    text: "STOP"
                    size_hint_x:0.2
                    bold :True
                    on_press: root.stop()
```

Comment: by the way, i have only just started learning python so i may not understand tecnical coding language. please bear with me

Answer (score 0):

You must handle keyword arguments when you extend a class. Just add that to your `Logic` class:

```
class Logic(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Logic,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.plot = MeshLinePlot(color=[1,0,0,1])
```

Comment: thank you so much. ive been stuck on ths for a week now